# VerifyError?: method: apply signature: ()Lcascading/pipe/Pipe;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call

Tags: scala, verifyerror, scalding

This happens when my code tries to invoke [Checkpoint](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/master/scalding-commons/src/main/scala/com/twitter/scalding/commons/extensions/Checkpoint.scala). I've cleaned & rebuilt.